# How to append div in a vue template

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a template which I run a for

```html
<tr v-for="entry in filteredData">
  <td>
    @{{ entry.position}}
  </td>
  <td :class="addNewElement(entry.value)">

  </td>
  <td>
    @{{ Math.round(entry.chanceOfApproval*100) }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

I need that the method `addNewElement` append a div into this column, but I don't know how can I do that in my template

Comment: You're not giving enough information. With a framework like Vue you wouldn't want to "append" a div normally. Instead generate them based on your data. Can you clarify your question a bit?

Comment: I have a javascript method in another file, that is returning a div and I need to append this div in the template

Comment: I edited the question for what I really need, it was bad written

Comment: I still can't understand what you want to achieve here, but seems like that you don't understand how VueJS works.

Check this example

https://jsbin.com/toratumumu/edit?html,js,output

You should have defined some data, and then work with them.

Comment: When I am just passing <div>something</div> the tags appear in my table

Comment: You should use 3 mustache syntax `{{{ dataObj }}}` and then it woul be parsed as HTML

Comment: but then I get this error [Vue warn]: failed to compile template:- invalid expression: {{{ test }}}

Comment: I am getting this error, because I am using vue 2.0. The right way of doing it in vue 2.0 is with v-html:dataObj. Thanks! You make me find the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the version of Vue.js you are using. For a given Vue instance

```
{
  ...
  methods: {
    renderEl() {
      return '<div>...</div>'
    }
  }
}
```

In Vue 1.x you can do ([docs](http://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML))

```
{{{ renderEl () }}}
```

In Vue 2.x you can do ([docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML))

```
<div v-html="renderEl()"></div>
```